# why i can not see any validate variable after a multi file in a grid?

Tags: gridview, datagridview, datagrid, grid, jqgrid

I use a multi file in a grid and a check box after that  and copy this dynaform for 3 steps of a process but dynaformes doesn't show check box inputs . I test it with a text box too and the problem repeat. is there any bug in grids that I cant see any  validate variables after a multi file in it?

Comment: Hello! Welcome to this forum. This is a good place to resolve your problem, but in order this to happen we need to understand the question. Usually if you ask something it is needed to post your code in order to see where is the problem. Sorry to say this, but your question is similar to "My car does not work - what to do?" Nobody can help you in this case. I recommend you to start [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: hi!thanx for your answer sorry i am new here. there is no problem in code and the problem is in a process grid . i can not attach "export process" here . can you help me?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid you use? How do you use multi file. Any code would be great appreciated.

Comment: my process maker version is 3.2.1-community . I made an input document then use a grid and then attached multi file in this grid and then related input document , that I made before , to the multi file and then in permission object , I permit to all user to use this. I have no code. I wish I could attach my process here . or if you can put your email that I can send you a sample of this problem.